# Ground coupling a high voltage source with the A_GND and D_GND

Tags: isolation, mains, grounding

I have a device that measures the current in the mains through a 0.01 Ohm 20W shunt resistor. The voltage across the shunt is amplified by a op amp and feed into a uC's ADC for farther calculations.

But to measure the voltage drop across the shunt the the mains needs to be ground coupled with the op amp and the rest of the components, which means that the D_GND and the A_GND will be 220 V above earth, and I feel very uncomfortable about that,

So what can be that to avoid raising the GND to such a high voltage?
I know one solution would be opto-coupling the signal, but it doesn't really fit in my project. Also a capacitor between the GND and the mains might work. Any thoughts?

Here is the schematics:

[image]

Comment: Mains current measurement is usually done with a current transformer, which avoids this problem.

Comment: Isn't one side of your mains connected to earth ground at some distribution point?

Comment: No, in EU a mains plug can be plugged both ways, which means you can end up having the GND connected to NULL or the live 220V line

Comment: How does opto-coupling "not really fit" in your project? It seems you have set up some impossible constraints.

Comment: Well, I could use an opto-coupler but I was looking for smaller, in size, alternatives

Comment: When dealing with mains going for the smallest size possible is making it harder on the design and build stages. I prefer a bit of space...

Comment: Well if you want to save space (and heat and money) you could get rid of the 20W power resistor.  Allegro makes some nice isolated current sense ICs. http://www.allegromicro.com/en/Products/Current-Sensor-ICs/Zero-To-Fifty-Amp-Integrated-Conductor-Sensor-ICs.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Optocoupler could be quite small, but a magnetic current sensor could be an alternative to provide isolation. Having a flowting transformer powersupply for the complete electronic would allow also to connect both grounds.